# Test statistics help needed

Tags: statistics

It has been claimed that at U.C.L.A. at least 40% of the students live on campus. From a 
sample of 250 students, 90 live on campus. Does the evidence support this claim at a
 = 0.01 .

What i did is

Ho: P is greater or equal to 0.4

Ha: P is less than 0.4

The critical value comes out to be -2.33 from the table

Now how to calculate the test statistics?

Comment: What is 'a'? What  statistics are you using? Also, can you improve the title?

Comment: a is alpha here

Comment: Can u please help me with the answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a statistics question (there's a forum for that) but I will answer anyway:

The sample proportion is $$\frac{90}{250}=0.36$$ so the sample standard error is $$\sqrt{\frac{0.36\cdot 0.64}{250}}\approx0.03$$ The $z$-score is therefore $$z=\frac{0.36-0.40}{0.03}=-1.33$$

You critical value looks wrong, I think at $99$% confidence you should have something like $2.56$?

Regardless, this will not be enough to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: It's $2.576$ not $2.56$.