# Help with null hypothesis

Tags: statistics

It has been claimed that at U.C.L.A. at least 40% of the students live on campus. From a 
sample of 250 students, 90 live on campus. Does the evidence support this claim at a
 = 0.01 .

What i did is

Ho: P is greater or equal to 0.4

Ha: P is less than 0.4

The critical value comes out to be -2.33 from the table

Now how to calculate the test statistics? Also is my critical value correct?

Comment: Do not post duplicate questions! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787090/test-statistics-help-needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of them as a sample of iid variables whose values are either zero or one and $\mu=p$.  Recall then that your test statistic, as always when testing for the mean with iid data, takes the form

$$\sqrt{n} \frac{\bar x - 0.4}{\hat\sigma},$$

where $\hat\sigma$ is the sample standard deviation which, in this very special case, you can replace with the known population standard deviation under $H_0$ if you wish.  Just plug in the numbers and you're done.

And yes, you looked it up correctly.

Comment: here n=250 and x=90. is that correct?

Comment: $n$ yes, $\bar x$ no.  $\bar x$ is the fraction of ones, i.e....?

Comment: is x=0.36 or 0.03?

Comment: and what will be sample standard deviation sir?

Comment: just imagine you have 90 ones and 160 zeroes.  What would the sd be of that?

Comment: 0.56 i guess. am i correct?

Comment: for this question it will be like 0.49. is that correct?